# array using a while loop to display in a bulleted list

Tags: while-loop, bulletedlist

I am very new to Javascript and am trying to recreate the following code using a While loop instead of a For loop. I can get it to list but not in an unordered list. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
var middle = "Wayne";
var streets = ["Elm Street", "Sesame Street", "Coronation Street", "Jump 
Street", "Wall Street"];
var sLen = streets.length;
var text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < sLen; i++){
text += "<li>" + middle + " " + streets[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("nameList").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Did you research this topic before posting here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
while(i<sLen){
   ...execution code goes here...  
   i++;
}
```

Please review this reference to learn more about while loops [while-loops-Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
var middle = "Wayne";  
var streets = ["Elm Street", "Sesame Street", "Coronation Street", "Jump 
Street", "Wall Street"];
var sLen = streets.length;
var text = "<ul>";

while(sLen--) {
    text += "<li>" + middle + " " + streets[sLen] + "</li>";
}

text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("nameList").innerHTML = text;
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: This works only for the first street name 5 times over. I got to this point as well but could not get it to take on the other 4 names.